# Python, Sorting a file

Tags: python

I want to make a function to sort through the data from the file and put it in a dictionary. I have made the following:

```
def fileread(filename, filetype, readlist):
returnslist = {}
with open(filename + "." + filetype, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for entry in readlist:
            if(line[:(entry.len() + 2)] == entry):
                returnslist[entry] = line[(entry.len() + 2):]
```

At the moment the laptop I am using can't use Python so I am working on an Online IDE which can't use files. Would this work? I want the file to work out like a config file. For example:

```
Int1: 2
Int2: 12
Int3: 32
Int4: 65
Str1: Lol
Bool1: True
```

My code should make the dictionary:

```
{"Int1": "2", "Int2": "12", "Int3": "32", "Int4": "65", "Str1": "Lol", "Bool1": "True"}
```

Is there a more cleaner way of doing this? I can't think of any. Also can you see any errors in this?

Comment: You could make a short minimal string with the file's format and use io.StringIO to emulate a file to see of your code works. https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

Comment: If you want to work with files on a online ide try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php

Comment: if you need something like "config file" then better use `pickle`, `YAML` or `JSON`.

Comment: if you have `Int1: 2` in file then read line, split it using `"Int1: 2".split(':')` and you get two strings `Int1` and `2` (with spaces so use `strip()`), and then you can check `if "Int1" in readlist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import yaml

my_data = """
    Int1: 2
    Int2: 12
    Int3: 32
    Int4: 65
    Str1: Lol
    Bool1: True
"""

data_dict = yaml.load(my_data)
```